# iOS Facebookk SDK 3 post not seen to friends post on my Timeline

Tags: ios, facebook

i am using Facebook SDK 3.0 for posting Feeds on my wall from iphone. I am using this code from facebook SDK example `Scrumptious`

```
 [FBRequestConnection
     startWithGraphPath:@"me/feed"
     parameters:self.postParams
     HTTPMethod:@"POST"
     completionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection,
                         id result,
                         NSError *error) {
}
```

and passing my `postParams` to the parameters . It is successfully posting on my wall and i am able to see my post. But when my friends go on my wall they are not able to see my post. i need that when i post anything using Facebook sdk  my friends able to see my post.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to change your App Settings in Facebook

First you go to Account Settings -> Applications -> Select your application -> Edit->Publications in your name:Who can see this application publications created by you in your biography of Facebook?

Then you change it for Friends or everything or u want

Comment: Thanks Xenetrix for your reply but its alreay set to Friends by default. i tried it with Everyone but is also not worked. :(